# WPF datagrid is not auto refreshing after certain interval of time?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I would like to auto refresh the datagrid after certain interval of time. I'm using MVVM model.

### adding Model - EmployeeDetails.cs

```
namespace AutoRefresh3.Model
{
   public class EmployeeDetails
    {
        private string name;
        private string location;
        private double salary;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                this.name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Location")]
        public string Location
        {
            get
            {
                return location;
            }

            set
            {
                this.location = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Location");
            }
        }
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Salary")]
        public double Salary
        {
            get
            {
                return salary;
            }

            set
            {
                this.salary = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Salary");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }


}
```

### adding ViewModel - EmployeeViewModel.cs

```
namespace AutoRefresh3.ViewModel
{
    class EmployeeViewModel
    {

        private ObservableCollection<EmployeeDetails> empdetails = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeDetails>();

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("EmpDetails")]
        public ObservableCollection<EmployeeDetails> EmpDetails
        {
            get
            {
                return empdetails;
            }
            set
            {
                value = empdetails;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("EmpDetails");
            }
        }

        public void LoadEmployees()
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EmployeeDetails));
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\xlf\employeedetails1.xml");
            object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
            EmployeeDetails ed = (EmployeeDetails)obj;
            empdetails.Add(ed);



            //EMPDetails empdetails = (EMPDetails)obj;
            //employees.Add(emp);
            //employees = (EmployeeDetails)empdetails;
        }

        public void setTimer()
        {
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

            timer.Start();
        }
        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadEmployees();
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### adding View- view.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="AutoRefresh3.View.view"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="view" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  x:Name="datagrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding EmpDetails}" 
                   Height="600" Margin="24,79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Location" Binding="{Binding Location}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Salary" Binding="{Binding Salary}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### view.xaml.cs

```
namespace AutoRefresh3.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for view.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class view : Window
    {
        public view()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            EmployeeViewModel ed = new EmployeeViewModel();
            this.DataContext = ed;
            ed.LoadEmployees();
            ed.setTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

### employeedetails1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<EmployeeDetails>


<Name>abc</Name>
<Location>Bangalore</Location>
<Salary>1000000</Salary>



<Name>def</Name>
<Location>Mysore</Location>
<Salary>2000000</Salary>



<Name>ghi</Name>
<Location>USA</Location>
<Salary>50000</Salary>

</EmployeeDetails>
```

The above project able to display only the first employee information in data grid and refreshes every 5 secs and displays only first record. I would like display all the data in xml every 5 secs ..How to accomplish this? What changes needs to be done?

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. Please add more details about the setup of your datagrid and maybe provide a sample of the data itself.

Comment: Could you please tell me which data? Data in XML?

Comment: Where is the code for `Items`?

Comment: @slugster please refer only these files EmployeeDetails.cs,EmployeeViewModel.cs,view.xaml,view.xaml.cs,employeedetails1.xml

Comment: @slugster not sure why downvote for this question?

Comment: @Skynet not sure why downvote for this question?

Comment: @meshsf I didn't downvote it, but i can fully understand why someone would do that. Just have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is the behaviour you are looking for.

It's important to use a collection that is observable (like `ObservableCollection`) else the View will never know anything changed.

This application generates new data every second. The changes are immediatly shown in the DataGrid.

**Code Behind**

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        datagrid1.DataContext = this;

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Employees.Add(new Employee
        {
            Name = "Name",
            Age = (new Random()).Next(0, 100)
        });
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="datagrid1" 
               AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Age">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: It's a great help. Helped me to proceed to some level in my problem. I'm adding my complete project now ..please check and help me.

Comment: I have added my complete project now. Could you help,please?

Comment: I modified the code to be easier to read/understand. You do not need to use any PropertyChanged events. In your case it may be a good idea to start a new project to experiment with DataBindings until you really understand them.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable PropertyChanged. I'm assuming that you've bound the itemsField to view. I believe your refresh is working. It's just not reflecting the changes in view.

```
Object_Type itemsField {
   set {
       this._itemsField = value;
       onPropertyChanged("itemsField");
       }
   get{
       return this._itemsField;
       }
    }

void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: Yes I had already enabled PropertyChanged. Sorry I did not add those code snippet above.

Comment: Nope. Could not figure out.

Comment: Can you share XAML?

Comment: Added the XAML.

Comment: It loads only on startup and any modification done in model doesn't reflect. Am I Right?

Comment: Yes you are right..If I change the data in XML file , the new data will not be updated in datagrid.

Comment: You will have to put OnPropertyChanged in item's model as well. Have you implemented that? i.e. for each property of item.

Comment: Please check I have updated my complete project now.